# Adding zkemkeeper dll to .net Core 2

Tags: c#, dll, asp.net-core-2.0

I have been at this for a couple of days now. I am trying to access the methods inside the zkemkeeper.dll. My web app is running on the .net core 2 framework. When I create an instance of the CZKEMClass or access any of its methods I receive the following
"FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.zkemkeeper, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified."

I tried recreating this scenario in a .net core 1 web app. At first it gave the same error message, however changing the project build target to x86 and changing the runtimeidentifier in the csproj loaded the dll methods successfully.

Back in the .net core 2 web app I tried to do the same, however I still get the same error message. I have tried creating a .net standard library and adding it to the solution, same result.

I am out of ideas on how to get this dll to work. :(

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are experiencing is due to the fact that zkemkeeper is not compatible with .Net core

```
ZM Keeper is not compatible with .net core 
Package 'ZKemkeeper 1.0.2' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

To resolve this you will need to create a .Net standard project and reference that project in your .Net core project.

I have created a github repo for reference:

https://github.com/chadatomixdev/ZKe